# How to automatically create more models in my environment changing 3 parameters at a time?

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation, forecast

A fully reproducible example.

```
library(forecast)
date = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)

productB = rep("B",48)
productB = rep("B",48)
productA = rep("A",48)
productA = rep("A",48)

subproducts1=rep("1",48)
subproducts2=rep("2",48)
subproductsx=rep("x",48)
subproductsy=rep("y",48)

b1 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b2 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b3 <-c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b4 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
```

Created the dataframe below

```
dfone <- data.frame("date"= rep(date,4),
            "product"= c(rep(productB,2),rep(productA,2)),
            "subproduct"= 
c(subproducts1,subproducts2,subproductsx,subproductsy),
            "actuals"= c(b1,b2,b3,b4))

export_df <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3])
```

## Creation of data frames based off UNIQUE SUBPRODUCTS

```
dummy_list <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3]) %>% lapply( function(x) 
x[(names(x) %in% c("date", "actuals"))])
dummy_list <-  lapply(dummy_list, function(x) { x["date"] <- NULL; x })


list_dfs <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(dfone$subproduct))) {
  #assign(paste0("df", i), as.data.frame(dummy_list[[i]]))
  list_dfs <-append(list_dfs,dummy_list[[i]])
}

combined_dfs <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE,  
by='date'), list(list_dfs))
```

Creating the time series

```
list_ts <- lapply(list_dfs, function(t) 
ts(t,start=c(2019,1),end=c(2021,6), frequency = 12)) %>%
  lapply( function(t) ts_split(t,sample.out=(0.2*length(t))))    # 
creates my train test split
list_ts <- do.call("rbind", list_ts)  #Creates a list of time series
```

Question. This doesn't give me more than 9 models. I'd want a model for n1 =.1 n2=.99 and n3= .3 for example so we would have way more than 9 models for this.

```
n1 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)
n2 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)
n3 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)

out<- lapply(seq_along(n1), function(i) {
   cw_triple_holtwinters_additive <- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
       forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha = 
n1[i],beta=n2[i],gamma=n3[i])))
    cw_triple_holtwinters_additive <- 
 lapply(cw_triple_holtwinters_additive, "[", "mean")
  assign(paste0("cw_triple_holtwinters_additive", i), 
cw_triple_holtwinters_additive, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 cw_triple_holtwinters_additive})
```

Additional question: for order=c(1,1,1) and order=c(0,1,0) can I create a list of values like these and loop through them both at the same time like Akrun's solution?

```
cw_seasonal_autoregressive_integratedmovingaverage1 <- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x)
 forecast::forecast(arima(x,order=c(1,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,0),
period=12)) ,h=24))

cw_seasonal_autoregressive_integratedmovingaverage1 <- 
lapply(cw_seasonal_autoregressive_integratedmovingaverage1, "[",  
c("mean"))
```

Comment: My doubt with the order is how likely it is varying for each input for n1, n2, n3

Comment: So there will be two different order= values so only n1 and n2. N2 will be fixed to about 8 different values and n1 will be up to 15 values.

Comment: Can you update your post with how those values changes for the dat_n.  From the comments it is n ot clear

Comment: Or do you want to repeat the same loop for c(1, 1, 1) and c(0, 1, 0).  Then just change the values to c(0, 1, 0) and may be rename the object

Comment: I will make a new post later it's okay.

Comment: that will be great as I am not able to follow what you want from the comments

Comment: I've made a new post, but I have a function that can find the accuracy of the model compared to it's test data. How would I add that to the solution provided so instead of creating 729 model objects, we can get only 1 or the best 5?

Comment: I am a bit busy now.  will look later

Comment: Ok thank you, take your time

Comment: Hey Akrun, I've been struggling with the formation for my new unanswered question. Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: sorry, was a bit busy with work.  I didn't get time to check the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` to get all the combinations

```
dat_n <- expand.grid(n1 = n1, n2= n2, n3 = n3)
```

Then, we loop over the sequence of rows of 'dat_n'

```
out<- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat_n)), function(i) {
   cw_triple_holtwinters_additive <- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
       forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha = 
dat_n$n1[i],beta=dat_n$n2[i],gamma=dat_n$n3[i])))
    cw_triple_holtwinters_additive <- 
 lapply(cw_triple_holtwinters_additive, "[", "mean")
  assign(paste0("cw_triple_holtwinters_additive", i), 
cw_triple_holtwinters_additive, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 cw_triple_holtwinters_additive})
```

-checking

```
 ls(pattern = "cw_triple")
  [1] "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive1"   "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive10"  "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive100" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive101"
  [5] "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive102" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive103" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive104" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive105"
  [9] "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive106" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive107" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive108" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive109"
 [13] "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive11"  "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive110" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive111" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive112"
 [17] "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive113" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive114" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive115" "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive116"
 [21] "cw_triple_holtwinters_additive117" 
...
```

Comment: Wow.. I didn't know expand.grid was the answer to my problem.. Thank you. I will accept your answer in 2 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: I will ask this in a new question, but if an argument takes this form order= c(1,2,3), and I have several of these, can I do the same thing but n1 would be a list of values like ((1,2,3),(2,0,1)) ?

Comment: @chriswang123 did you meant `c(1, 2, 3)` as `c(dat_n$n1[i],dat_n$n2[i],dat_n$ n3[i])`

Comment: @chriswang123 or did you meant `n1` to take multiple values, n2 to take multiple values etc.  In the code, we are looping over the rows, that implies when you subset with `n1[i]` or `n2[i]`, there will be a single value for that loop

Comment: I've explained what I mean, in an edit above. Basically each c(1,2,3) is it's own individual arguement. Before 0.1 was a value to take in, now it's c(1,0,0). So i think creating a list of values would be the solution. I will try modifying your solution to fix mine, but will make a new question when I'm able to later.

Comment: @chriswang123  I understand what you meant.  You can create a combinations of that with expand.grid or so, i.e. `expand.grid(v1 = c(0:2), v2 = 0:3, v3 = 0.4)`, but the number of rows of this should also match the `dat_n` number of rows

Comment: In the expand.grid, created with 'dat_n' there are 729 rows.  If you creating a list, the length should be 729 because we are looping over the rows.  In that case, we can use the same index for subsetting both

Comment: Ok on the current question that you already solved. I created 99 new list objects from your code. Is there a way to check what parameters went in to the 99 new list objects? And is 99 new list objects the expected output or 729?

Comment: @chriswang123 basd on the example, it should be 729 because it is the number of rows of dat_n and we create 729 objects by pasteing `paste0("cw_triple_holtwinters_additive", i)`

Comment: @chriswang123 I am not sure how you want to map the 99 to 729.  Is there any pattern i..e the `n1 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)` which is of length 9 `length(n1)
[1] 9`

Comment: Ok my confusion is why isn't there 729 new objects in the environment but only 99 then. Is there a limit?

Comment: @chriswang123 no, there is no limit.  Do you have `nrow(dat_n)` as 729

Comment: Yes I do have nrow(dat_n) as 729

Comment: @chriswang123 it is very easy to understand which value of n1, n2, n3 are there in model. i.e. our model objects are created in sequence i..e `cw_triple_holtwinters_additive1` will have the input parameters from the first row of dat_n, and so on

Comment: @chriswang123 then try on a fresh R session with all objects deleted and see if you are able to replicate 729 objects

Comment: @chriswang123 for me, `length( ls(pattern = "cw_triple"))#
[1] 729`

Comment: It works now after refresh. Thank you again. I will try to figure out my other question and if not post a new question.

Comment: I've created a new question. Thanks so much again.